# uninstall extras installed by apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I ran `apt-get install gnome-terminal` and `apt-get install gnome-desktop` on my linux box. It was just a command line box before that. Both of these things had like around 100mb of files to install - I guess dependencies?

Anyhow, I then ran `apt-get remove` for both of them and it only remove like a few megabytes. So I suppose it left the dependencies on the system? How can I remove all the other stuff that was installed with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `apt-get autoremove` to remove all packages that were marked as automatically installed, and that are no longer used by any package that's marked as manually installed.

Comment: wow this is very helpful to know!